# Remove an android Chip from a Chip Group smoothly

Tags: android, android-animation, androidx, android-chips

In one of the fragments of the app i'm developing, i let the users create various **chips** and every chip represents an option. I was able to **animate** the chip creation.

Now, when the user taps on a chip, i remove it from the group. I was able to associate a custom animation to the removal (see the gif) but when a "middle chip" is deleted, the chips to the right **suddenly move** to the left, when the animation is over.

[image]

**Layout:**

```
       <HorizontalScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/horizontal_scroll_height"
           android:scrollbars="none">

           <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
               android:id="@+id/rouletteChipList"
               style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ChipGroup"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingStart="@dimen/chip_horizontal_margin"
               android:paddingEnd="@dimen/chip_horizontal_margin"
               app:chipSpacing="@dimen/chip_spacing"
               app:singleLine="true">

           </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
       </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Chip deletion:**

```
private void removeChip(final Chip chip) {
        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions") final ChipGroup optionsList = getView().findViewById(R.id.ChipList);
        // Remove the chip with an animation
        if (chip == null) return;
        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.chip_exit_anim);
        chip.startAnimation(animation);
        chip.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                optionsList.removeView(chip);
            }
        }, 400);
}
```

**Chip layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/placeholder"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/grayTranslucent"
    app:rippleColor="?colorAccent" />
```

I'd like to have a **smooth animation**, where the chips smoothly move to the left when a "middle chip" is deleted. I tried a couple of things, but no luck.

Comment: Use a RecyclerView instead of a HorizontalScrollView

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I never used any RecyclerView, sadly

Comment: Not so simple. In the catalog of the material components library there is [an example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/3e55f14f7b1dae604f31b1b000904f8ee2e0e5a5/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/chip/ChipRecyclerviewDemoFragment.java) with Chips and a RecyclerView. There isn't the animation on remove, but it a simple animation on recyclerview.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. I'll update the question with any progress.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you mean something like this

[image: animate remove chips]

i,ve added it inside a HSV and added `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on `chip_group`, see below code

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        .
        >
        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chip_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

inside my Code i have added chips dynamically to this `chip_group`.

```
val newChip = Chip(this, null, R.attr.chipStyle)
newChip.text = "text"
newChip.isClickable = true
newChip.isFocusable = true
newChip.setOnClickListener(chipClickListener)
chip_group.addView(newChip)
```

and there is a `onClickListener` on each chip.inside it i start a fade animation and in `onAnimationEnd` do a `removeView` on `chip_group`

```
private val chipClickListener = View.OnClickListener {

        val anim = AlphaAnimation(1f,0f)
        anim.duration = 250
        anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                chip_group.removeView(it)
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}
        })

        it.startAnimation(anim)
    }
```

Comment: @m.i.n.a.r. : Okey I am waiting for you :D

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot, i was lost in complicated workarounds and it was just a line :D